# illegal start of expression: Java Method

Tags: java, function, methods, output, call

Does anyone know why this method will not let me call it. I'm trying to make sure I can call a method with no parameters before I start writing my code. Is there some package or something I need or can someone explain what's going on. Thanks in advance. I'm getting an java: illegal start of expression and red line under () next to validate.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.lang.Math;

 /// Start Program
public class javamethods {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    validate();


    public static void validate() {

        System.out.print("Hi World");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You defined `validate` inside of another method, but you should include it at the `class` level. In other words, place `}` after `validate();`

Comment: Awww Thank you. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The method `validate` may not be defined *inside* the `main` method.

Instead, do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    validate();
}

public static void validate() {

    System.out.print("Hi World");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your curly brace order mixed up; and in doing so, have declared a new method within the main method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

/// Start Program
public class javamethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

// Create Scanner object
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

validate();


public static void validate() {

    System.out.print("Hi World");
    }
  }
}
```

You should declare your methods at the class level.

Change your code to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

 /// Start Program
 public class javaMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    validate();
}

public static void validate() {

    System.out.print("Hi World");
  }
}
```